# Make text in sharepoint left navigation as hyperlink

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am using calendars in Sharepoint 2016. I created Team Calendar as below in image. However it is not hyperlink. I need that as hyperlink. I have code which works in console, but not when added in script editor

```js
 $('.ms-acal-apanel > ul >li > ul > li > span').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="https://surendramouryacg.sharepoint.com/sites/testlearn/Lists/Team%20Calendar/calendar.aspxx" />');
});
```

[image: left navifation]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add script editor content like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMyLinks(){
$('.ms-acal-apanel > ul >li > ul > li > span').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="https://surendramouryacg.sharepoint.com/sites/testlearn/Lists/Team%20Calendar/calendar.aspxx" />');
});
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("initMyLinks");
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function initMyLinks(){
            $('.ms-acal-apanel > ul >li > ul > li > span').each(function(){
                $(this).wrapInner('<a href="https://surendramouryacg.sharepoint.com/sites/testlearn/Lists/Team%20Calendar/calendar.aspxx" />');
            });
            }
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(initMyLinks);
</script>
```